# The enthusiast badge: does it encompass every community you're part of?

Tags: support, badges, activity-badges

In order to get the enthusiast badge do you have to visit every community or is stackexchange enough?  Also, I noticed (can't find the example now) that there's a community (probably more than one) that has a different domain.  What do you do for the badge then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No - the Enthusiast and Fanatic badges (like all other ones) are kept track of *per community* - and you can even earn them for Meta sites. The easiest way to see this is to look at the badge progress indicator in your profile. You'll need to select the Enthusiast badge manually, and after that it will show a different progress on different sites.

Comment: AFAIK *all* badges are per-site/subsite.

Comment: @Meta'sMug thanks, you're right. Quorum and Convention are the only ones which aren't constrained to a single *site* - there are as of yet no *community*-transcending badges.